# What is this electrical symbol? T with overbar in down-pointing triangle

Tags: power-supply, safety, symbol

I'd like to use an old laptop AC adapter in conjunction with an adjustable buck module as a project power supply.

It works, but I'm ignorant of some safety details; for example I'm uncertain whether my adapter, which uses a non-earthed input, is "isolated from the mains".

I've tried researching the symbols on the label, but one symbol which feels relevant I cannot identify:

[image]

[image]

What is that letter T in a triangle?

Does it mean "safe"?

Or "death"...?

Comment: People use that for charging laptops and have survived. Thus it must be isolated. I do love the exclamation mark, as if it says "Warning: Made in China".

Comment: I've scoured the internet trying to figure out this symbol, including reverse image searches. The best theory I have is that it's something proprietary to Astec (now Artesyn, a subsidiary of Emerson). I don't believe it is a symbol related to compliance or safety.

Comment: You're joking right? What would you expect from a Dell approved source? and you aren't concerned about the Made In China Symbol /!\

Comment: it could be a stylized battery symbol

Comment: @Justme Thanks for the reassurance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Older symbol for Japan's Product Safety Electrical Appliance & Material.  Replace by the second symbol.

[image]

From [Product Approval Markings](https://www.swe-check.com.au/pages/learn_product_approvals.php)

Comment: WTG ssrat......

Comment: So the symbol is not as specifically relevant as I thought. But nice find, thank you.